# Difference in definition for logic terms versus rhetoric

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus

Why do the definitions for logic terms differ from the common English definitions?

From the Wikipedia page on [Tautology(logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)):

" In logic, a tautology (from Greek: ταυτολογία) is a formula or assertion that is true in every possible interpretation. An example is "x=y or x≠y". A less abstract example is "The ball is all green, or the ball is not all green". This would be a tautology regardless of the color of the ball.

The philosopher Ludwig Wittgenstein first applied the term to redundancies of propositional logic in 1921, borrowing from rhetoric, where a tautology is a repetitive statement."

From my understanding redundancy in a set of statements is not equivalent to true in every possible interpretation.

Comment: For the same reason mathematical, physical, biological, etc., definitions differ from those in common English. They are made more precise and/or specialized to uses in those fields. Common "repetitive" is either too narrow if taken literally (one can rephrase in a logically equivalent way without literally repeating), or too vague if taken figuratively. But tautologies, being always true, do not add any new information, and so, in a sense, "repeat the obvious".

Comment: "redundancy in a set of statements is not equivalent to true in every possible interpretation." Correct: the term *tautology* in logic is defined as "valid formula of propositional calculus" and it is defined rigorously through truth table (or truth assignment". The link with the everyday term is feeble, as always with scientific terms.

Comment: [Wittgenstein (1921)](http://www.bazzocchi.net/wittgenstein/tractatus/eng/4_46.htm) does not speak of *redundancy*: "**4.46** Among the possible groups of truth-conditions there are two extreme cases. In one of these cases the proposition is true for all the truth-possibilities of the elementary propositions. We
say that the truth-conditions are *tautological*. In the second case the proposition is false for all the truth-possibilities: the truth-conditions are *contradictory*.
In the first case we call the proposition a *tautology*; in the second, a contradiction."

Comment: Conifold's comment is completely bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you're absolutely correct in saying that redundancy is not equal to true,  tautologies in Logic are statements that are always true, it's just a definition of tautology in Logic. Also the philosopher Ludwig Wittgenstein could apply any term to anything from anywhere, it doesn't change any definition.